# How can I offer to my users the viewing and editing online functionnaliis of Microsoft documents?

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, office365

I search a solution for offering to users of my webapp (~ 200 000, but they are not all active) the possibility to edit and view Microsoft documents : Word, Excel and Powerpoint directly in my application.

I found the solution with the WOPI protocol : http://wopi.readthedocs.org/.
This is doing all I want, but it's necessary to have Microsoft online services.

Ok for the technical solution.

But I haven't found precise answer for : the prices and the conditions of use (user licences, limitations, ...) of the Microsoft services.

I found this : 
- "Cloud Storage Partner" web page (http://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage) : not found the partnership and prices conditions
- Instanciate my own Office Web App Server : not found the price for my number of potential users
- others solutions ?

Have you already implemented a WOPI  server and which Microsoft services or/and contactual formula ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a WOPI server, you can use the 3rd party components to complete your task. Try the [ASPxRichEdit](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxRichEditDemos/Default.aspx) and [ASPxSpreadSheet](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSpreadSheetDemos/) controls from DevExpress.

They support all popular documents formats, including DOCx, DOC, RTF, XLSx and XLS, have the built-in adaptive ribbon, and a huge number of features: mail merge, document management (via built-in filemanager), client and server-side API, the most of rich text formatting, and etc.

Comment: I must use Microsoft Office Online, it's a prerequisite.